# Trying to implement React Suspense boundary and refetching data from API after some events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-suspense

Hey im pretty new to React and JS.

Im trying to implement the React Suspense boundary for a component that requires fechting data from my backend API.
I used the fetchData and wrapPromise function from this example [https://dev.to/darkmavis1980/a-practical-example-of-suspense-in-react-18-3lln](A practical example of Suspense in React 18 ).

wrapPromise function:

```
/**
 * Wraps a promise so it can be used with React Suspense
 * @param {Promise} promise The promise to process
 * @returns {Object} A response object compatible with Suspense
 */
function wrapPromise(promise) {
  let status = "pending";
  let response;

  const suspender = promise.then(
    (res) => {
      status = "success";
      response = res;
    },
    (err) => {
      status = "error";
      response = err;
    }
  );

  const handler = {
    pending: () => {
      throw suspender;
    },
    error: () => {
      throw response;
    },
    default: () => response,
  };

  const read = () => {
    const result = handler[status] ? handler[status]() : handler.default();
    return result;
  };

  return { read };
}

export default wrapPromise;
```

fetchData function:

```
 * Wrap Axios Request with the wrapPromise function
 * @param
 * @returns {Promise} A wrapped promise
 */
function fetchData(url) {
  const promise = axios.get(url).then(({ data }) => data);

  return wrapPromise(promise);
}

export default fetchData;
```

So i created a component RecipeTableMain to render the recipe data:

```
import fetchData from "../../api/fetchData";

const resource = fetchData("http://localhost:3001/recipes");
...

export default function RecipeTableMain() {
  const data = resource.read(); //Calling read function from wrapPromise

... some code for mui data grid
}
```

**My Problem is:**
The data only gets fetched on the first render of RecipeTableMain component (After i reload my app).
I tried to find a way to fetch the data again for example after deleting or creating a new recipe,
but i have no idea how i could implement this in my code.

Thanks Jonas.

I think i missed some basics about how code outside of React components is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the user from this post:

[Infinite loop when using React Suspense and Axios data fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74507775/infinite-loop-when-using-react-suspense-and-axios-data-fetch?rq=2)

I ditched the wrapPromise() function, and used the useSWR hook instead.

I also modified the fetchData() function:

```
import axios from "axios";

/**
 * Wrap Axios Request with the wrapPromise function
 * @param {String} URL Endpoint
 */
async function fetchData(url) {
  return axios
    .get(url)
    .then(({ data }) => data)
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

export default fetchData;
```

And i call it like this:

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import fetchData from "../../api/fetchData";

export default function RecipeTableMain() {

  const url = "http://localhost:3001/recipes";
  const fetcher = (url) => fetchData(url);
  const { data } = useSWR(url, fetcher, {
    suspense: true,
  });
...
}
```

Now the data gets fetched on every render of the component and i can also pass an route id from react router if necessary.