# React suspense for data fetching - use props in promise

Tags: reactjs, react-suspense

I have a bunch of async actions I need to do before a react component can be rendered, and I would like to use `React.Suspense` for this. I found an example online:

https://dev.to/smitterhane/swap-out-useeffect-with-suspense-for-data-fetching-in-react-2leb

```js
import React from "react";
import Post from "./Post";

// Variables we will use to replay state of fetch() promise to React
let status = "pending";
let result;

// Start fetching posts even before rendering begins
const userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser"))?.id;
const postsData = fetchPosts(userId);

// Posts component (definition)
const Posts = () => {
  // No need for loading states
  const posts = postsData();
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", gap: "10px" }}>
      {posts.map((post, idx) => (
        <Post post={post} key={idx} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

// Fetch external data
function fetchPosts(userId) {
  let url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts${
    userId ? "?userId=" + userId : ""
  }`;
  let fetching = fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    // Fetch request has gone well
    .then((success) => {
      status = "fulfilled";

      result = success;
    })
    // Fetch request has failed
    .catch((error) => {
      status = "rejected";

      result = error;
    });

  return () => {
    if (status === "pending") {
      throw fetching; // Suspend(A way to tell React data is still fetching)
    } else if (status === "rejected") {
      throw result; // Result is an error
    } else if (status === "fulfilled") {
      return result; // Result is a fulfilled promise
    }
  };
}

export default Posts;
```

But what if, in this example, `userId` would be a prop of Posts - rather than taken from localstorage?

```
const Posts = ({ userId } ) => {
```

This seems to be a problem because `const postsData = fetchPosts(userId);` is declared *outside* of the Posts component...

Comment: Checkout https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense. Specifically the Note section in the midddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the user from this post:

[Trying to implement React Suspense boundary and refetching data from API after some events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76643668/trying-to-implement-react-suspense-boundary-and-refetching-data-from-api-after-s/76656729#76656729)

I ditched all these half-functiong tutorials online, and used the useSWR hook instead.